# Determining ring of integers using Computer Algebra Systems

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I am working on ring of integers of given number fields. Are there any computer algebra systems that I can use to determine the ring of integers $O_K$ of a number field $K$? I am aware that  I can ask my questions here but I need this to get quick answers and investigate their properties.Lastly, I have spent a lot time on Magma CAS, so I appreciate any answers related to Magma but other cas advices are also would be great.

Answer (score 1):

With [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/97ce992e-ba7e-4176-8c00-4cb08a48b48f/files/class%20group%20-%20extension%20of%20degree%203.sagews) :

```
 P = x^3-x^2-2*x-8
 K.<a> = NumberField(P)
 OK = K.ring_of_integers()
 OK.basis()
 >> [1, 1/2*a^2 + 1/2*a, a^2]
```

And with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ :

```
K.<a,b> = NumberField([x^2-2,x^2-3])
OK = K.ring_of_integers()
OK.basis()
>> [(-3/2*b + 17/2)*a - 7*b + 4, 6*a - 5*b, -2*b*a + 5, 11*a - 9*b]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please suggest me a sage booklet including examples for abstract algebra if you know any?

Comment: @Ninja https://www.google.fr/search?q=sage+number+field  https://www.google.fr/search?q=magma+number+field

Comment: By any chance do you know about Wolfram Mathematica? It can factor Gaussian integers and you can query fundamental units, class numbers and regulators, but as far as I know it has no built-in way to  query integral bases.

Comment: Oops, never mind, just found https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberFieldIntegralBasis.html

Comment: @Mr.Brooks I'm not sure using Mathematica (instead of Sage or Magma) for number fields is a so good idea.

Comment: Yeah, the results leave something to be desired...